# Maven project configuration required for module

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I'm trying to compile a project in Android Studio 1.2.1.1 and getting the following error:

```
Error:Maven Resources Compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'slidingmenu' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.
```

I can't find any info in the internet about this error. How do I fix it?

Comment: is there a pom.xml file in your project? Maven needs a pom.xml to run (project object model). Most Maven commands only run in directories that contain this file.

Answer (score 0):

I had two git branches of the app: one branch was using gradle and the other branch was using maven and ant. I checked out the branch with gradle and then switched two another one and then hit this error. The solution was to checkout maven+ant branch into an empty folder.