# Maven project configuration required for module not available

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have a Java/Maven/JSP runs with the Tomcat 8 server. The project structure is as following,

[image]

I have this `pom.xml` file provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.puut.wallet</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>WalletApp</artifactId>
    <name>simple-bitcoin-wallet</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
        <artifactId>bitcoinj-parent</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
            <artifactId>bitcoinj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run the project, I get the following error,

```
Error:Maven Resources Compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'WalletApp' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE.
```

I took several measures,

```
a. in the terminal, run `mvn clean`
b. project -> right click -> `Make Module WalletApp`
c. project -> right click -> `Recompile Module WalletApp`
d. File -> Invalide Caches/Restart .... [This restarts the project]
e. Synchronize
```

Obviously, none of them worked out to resolve the issue. By the way, I use `InteliIJ` for the project. What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013337/maven-error-maven-project-configuration-for-module-isnt-availabe

Comment: I tried solution from that question earlier. It didn't work and still get the same error.

Comment: On the right side of the IDE you should see s `Maven projects` button. If you click, can you see your project in the tool window? If not, try clicking the little _refresh_ button. Does anything change? P.S. you're missing the `target` directory from your project structure, but it will probably be created automatically after importing the project as a maven project. Also you can use @user when replying to someone, so they get a notification :-)

Comment: Delete ipr/iws/iml files, .idea directory and open pom.xml from the welcome screen to import the Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `Event Log`, I get an option to `Add as maven project`. I selected that option and the issue is immediately solved.

[image]